# setTimeout for XHR requests

Tags: javascript, settimeout

quoting [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval):

> If there is a possibility that your logic could take longer to execute than the interval time, it is recommended that you recursively call a named function using window.setTimeout.  For example, if using setInterval to poll a remote server every 5 seconds, network latency, an unresponsive server, and a host of other issues could prevent the request from completing in its alloted time.  As such, you may find yourself with queued up XHR requests that won't necessarily return in order.
>
> For such cases, a recursive setTimeout pattern is preferred:

```
(function loop(){
   setTimeout(function(){

      // logic here

      // recurse
      loop();

  }, 1000);
})();
```

> In the above snippet, a named function loop is declared and is immediately executed.  loop is recursively called inside setTimeout after the logic has completed executing.  While this pattern does not guarantee execution on a fixed interval, it does guarantee that the previous interval has completed before recursing.

I don't understand how this fixes the problem. Shouldn't I call loop() from inside the XHR callback and not from setTimeout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original problem is related to `setInterval()`: it's possible for two or more AJAX requests to be sent before the reply to the first one is received (depending on the network latency and the timer delay). If that happens, their respective callbacks are not guaranteed to be called in order.

The solution is to delay each request independently with `setTimeout()` and only schedule the next request after the current request has returned (i.e. in that request's callback).

So, you're absolutely right: calling `setTimeout()` (through `loop()`) from the delayed function itself only reimplements a poorer `setInterval()`. You indeed have to call `loop()` from the AJAX callback to obtain the expected behavior.

Comment: Cool. btw, why all this hassle? Last time I did something like this I just used timestamps..

Comment: Maybe because, though it's lengthy to explain, it's shorter to code than timestamps. YMMV, of course :)

Comment: While we are on the subject: won't this method return max recourse error somewhere along the road? e.g. just wrote this in firebug: `function x() {
   return y();
}

function y() {
    return x();
}

x();` and it returned max recurse.

Comment: The calls in your example are indeed recursive, but callbacks do not follow the same principle and are *not* recursive calls. Both the delayed functions passed to `setInterval()/setTimeout()` and the XHR callbacks are called by the interpreter itself, not by the function that called `setInterval()/setTimeout()/open()` in the first place. The stack is clean.

Comment: ok. got you. here's something weird though: `function x(f) {
 f(this);
}
function y(f) {
  f(this);
}

x(y);`. I don't even understand what I just wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The issue at hand is not executing single XHR request but rather repeatedly sending requests to the server at regular intervals.

Suppose you want to poll the server every five seconds and parse the response. You will just use `setInterval()` for this, causing XHR request to be created and sent every five seconds.

Now if there is some block in traffic or server is slow/overloaded there is chance that request A is sent and the server did not finish to process it when you send request B - that's what they mean by "queued up XHR requests" as far as I understand.

The solution in my opinion is not using `setInterval()` at all, but rather call the "next" XHR request only from within the callback of the previous request, possibly by using the `setTimeout()` as well to ensure it will "wait" the proper amount of time before polling again.