# When is a new connection made by browser for ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, http, browser

I noticed that for some of my ajax request's extra time for connecting is being used,it almost comes to around 1s which makes the request slow.Once a request is made the subsequent request does not take time for connection establishing.But if I leave it unattended for a while again it makes new connection.I can't really figure out in which condition the browser makes a new connection.I checked in other sites(gmail,stackoverflow) to  verify if their ajax requests too make an initial connection ,but couldn't find any.Is there any way to avoid this connection establishment ?

Comment: Thic could be bound to keep-alive timing setup in your browser (and server). The brute-force approach is to send 'ping' requests between your actual requests, just to see if this helps.

Comment: @Stan: Couldn't understand.Pls elaborate.

Comment: I suppose the browser keeps an open connection for a keep-alive period, and reuse the connection if a new request is made before timeout. If you issue dummy requests just to keep the connection opened, it will not be closed until the next work request, and will eliminate overheads for establishing new connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase the timeouts of your AJAX request, so that your XHRs will remain alive  for more time.Also try to use the same XHR objects(after flushing) when you want to reconnect to server for the same service/resource.However some times, if browser finds the requested data in cache then it may avoid to request server again for the same. Also one more reason may be that each time your URL is getting changed unnecessarily, so that browser forcefully need to request server(not much sure about this).

**UPDATE**

```
var xhr;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.timeout = 10000;
xhr.ontimeout = timeoutFired;
xhr.send(null);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6888409/1130032) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: How to set longer time-out's ? also i'm using post request and there is no cached data.